# Find whether each row in Matlab is repeated or not

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `A` in Matlab of dimension `MXN`. I want to create a vector `B` of dimension `Mx1` where `B(i)=1` if `A(i,:)` is never repeated in `A` more than once and `0` otherwise.

For example

```
A=[1 2 3;
   4 5 6; 
   1 2 3;
   7 8 9];

B=[0;1;0;1];
```

This code

```
[vu,vx,vx]=unique(A,'rows');
n=accumarray(vx,1);
C=[vu n]
```

helps to find the number of occurrences per row. Hence, by adding a loop for example, I should be able from `C` to get `B` as desired. However, in my actual case `M` is very large (80000). Is there anything quicker I could use?

Comment: Apologies, my mistake

Comment: Your code example errors on `Error using horzcat Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.`

Comment: Using `vx` twice for different outputs doesn't necessarily make the example any better...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the second output of `unique` only returns the *first occurance* of each unique value and the third output returns an array of indices into the first output that correspond to the input. Neither of these can directly get you what you want. If you combine them, you can get what you want

```
[~, a, b] = unique(A, 'rows');
B = accumarray(a(b), 1, [size(A, 1), 1]) == 1;
```

Another alternative is to use the second output of `ismember` with the `'rows'` option to find the indices of the shared rows. You can then use `accumarray` to determine how many times a row is repeated and compare the result to `1`

```
[~, bi] = ismember(A, A, 'rows');
B = accumarray(bi, 1, [size(A, 1), 1]) == 1;
```

In a simple benchmark, the option using `unique` tends to yield the best result

```
function comparison()

    nRows = round(linspace(100, 100000, 30));

    times1 = nan(size(nRows));
    times2 = nan(size(nRows));

    for k = 1:numel(nRows)
        A = randi(10, nRows(k), 4);
        times1(k) = timeit(@()option1(A));
        times2(k) = timeit(@()option2(A));
    end

    figure
    p(1) = plot(nRows, times1 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'unique');
    hold on
    p(2) = plot(nRows, times2 * 1000, 'DisplayName', 'ismember');
    ylabel('Execution time (ms)')
    xlabel('Rows in A')
    legend(p)
end


function B = option1(A)
    [~, a, b] = unique(A, 'rows');
    B = accumarray(a(b), 1, [size(A, 1), 1]) == 1;
end

function B = option2(A)
    [~, bi] = ismember(A, A, 'rows');
    B = accumarray(bi, 1, [size(A, 1), 1]) == 1;
end
```

[image]

Comment: Great benchmark. The peaks on same places are very interesting. Do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: @Adiel The peaks are likely spurious and are related to the load on my machine at the time of the tests. You could re-run the benchmark many times to get a smoother curve.

Comment: @Suever I am using the unique alternative, but I get one element less  when I do accummarray

Comment: @user3285148 Oops. yea I meant to add a third input to `accumarray` to ensure the proper output size. Try the updated code.